# Is there a single line way that I can reduce a string consisting of two words into one?

Tags: javascript

I have a string which can be one or two words like this:

```
var str = "John Smith"
var str = "John"
```

I realize I could use split to divide this into an array and then assign the output of the first element of the array.  However is there a more simple one line way that I can just extract the first word?

Comment: `var str = "John Smith".split(' ')[0]`, Just used your approach in single line

Comment: Or a regex: `var str = "John Smith".match(/^\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/)[0];` https://jsfiddle.net/6m02mkhg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "John Smith";
var str = str.substr(0, str.indexOf(' '))
```

Comment: Well this way is faster compare to split. But, there is a catch here, it is assuming that name contains more than one word. If there is one word say ("John") then output will be empty string ("").

Answer (score 0):

simple enough

```
> x = "Alley Halley"
'Alley Halley'
> x.split(" ")[0]
'Alley'
> x = "Alley"
'Alley'
> x.split(" ")[0]
'Alley'
```

or as a function

```
> firstBeforeSpace = function(str) { return str.split(" ")[0];  }
[Function]
> firstBeforeSpace("Halley")
'Halley'
> firstBeforeSpace("Halley Alley")
'Halley'
> firstBeforeSpace("Walley Halley Alley")
'Walley'
> x = "halley Alley Walley"
'halley Alley Walley'
> x.split(" ")[0]
'halley'
>
```